# Does there exists a stop running code button in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Vscode, supposing the package Code Runner is installed, there exists a triangle button that runs your code in terminal when pressed. Can I add a similar button, for example, in the shape of a square, whose function should be to stop the code that is already running?